# ScriptLogic , how can i avoid hardcode

Tags: java

This is the code i've found today, can I declare local var to use for ? I need to do this without the hardcode and i need to do it until 2040 for example, the previous employee do it this way, i think there must be a better way.
I'm a trainee on java, don't know why i'm doing this rn but my boss told me if I could help him

```
*WHEN VERSION
*IS <> ACTUAL
*WHEN FLOW
    *IS F10
    *WHEN TIME
        *IS 2012.01
        *REC(FACTOR = 1)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2012.02)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2012.03)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2012.04)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2012.05)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2012.06)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2012.07)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2012.08)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2012.09)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2012.10)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2012.11)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2012.12)

        *IS 2012.02
        *REC(FACTOR = 1)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2012.03)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2012.04)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2012.05)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2012.06)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2012.07)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2012.08)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2012.09)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2012.10)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2012.11)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2012.12)

        *IS 2012.03
        *REC(FACTOR = 1)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2012.04)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2012.05)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2012.06)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2012.07)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2012.08)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2012.09)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2012.10)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2012.11)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2012.12)

        *IS 2012.04
        *REC(FACTOR = 1)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2012.05)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2012.06)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2012.07)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2012.08)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2012.09)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2012.10)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2012.11)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2012.12)

        *IS 2012.05
        *REC(FACTOR = 1)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2012.06)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2012.07)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2012.08)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2012.09)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2012.10)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2012.11)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2012.12)

        *IS 2012.06
        *REC(FACTOR = 1)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2012.07)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2012.08)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2012.09)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2012.10)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2012.11)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2012.12)

        *IS 2012.07
        *REC(FACTOR = 1)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2012.08)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2012.09)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2012.10)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2012.11)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2012.12)

        *IS 2012.08
        *REC(FACTOR = 1)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2012.09)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2012.10)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2012.11)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2012.12)

        *IS 2012.09
        *REC(FACTOR = 1)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2012.10)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2012.11)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2012.12)

        *IS 2012.10
        *REC(FACTOR = 1)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2012.11)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2012.12)

        *IS 2012.11
        *REC(FACTOR = 1)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2012.12)

        *IS 2012.12
        *REC(FACTOR = 1)

        *IS 2013.01
        *REC(FACTOR = 1)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2013.02)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2013.03)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2013.04)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2013.05)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2013.06)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2013.07)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2013.08)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2013.09)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2013.10)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2013.11)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2013.12)

        *IS 2013.02
        *REC(FACTOR = 1)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2013.03)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2013.04)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2013.05)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2013.06)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2013.07)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2013.08)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2013.09)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2013.10)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2013.11)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2013.12)

        *IS 2013.03
        *REC(FACTOR = 1)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2013.04)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2013.05)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2013.06)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2013.07)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2013.08)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2013.09)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2013.10)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2013.11)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2013.12)

        *IS 2013.04
        *REC(FACTOR = 1)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2013.05)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2013.06)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2013.07)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2013.08)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2013.09)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2013.10)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2013.11)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2013.12)

        *IS 2013.05
        *REC(FACTOR = 1)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2013.06)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2013.07)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2013.08)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2013.09)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2013.10)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2013.11)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2013.12)

        *IS 2013.06
        *REC(FACTOR = 1)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2013.07)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2013.08)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2013.09)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2013.10)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2013.11)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2013.12)

        *IS 2013.07
        *REC(FACTOR = 1)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2013.08)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2013.09)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2013.10)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2013.11)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2013.12)

        *IS 2013.08
        *REC(FACTOR = 1)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2013.09)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2013.10)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2013.11)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2013.12)

        *IS 2013.09
        *REC(FACTOR = 1)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2013.10)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2013.11)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2013.12)

        *IS 2013.10
        *REC(FACTOR = 1)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2013.11)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2013.12)

        *IS 2013.11
        *REC(FACTOR = 1)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2013.12)

        *IS 2013.12
        *REC(FACTOR = 1)

        *IS 2014.01
        *REC(FACTOR = 1)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2014.02)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2014.03)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2014.04)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2014.05)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2014.06)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2014.07)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2014.08)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2014.09)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2014.10)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2014.11)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2014.12)

        *IS 2014.02
        *REC(FACTOR = 1)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2014.03)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2014.04)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2014.05)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2014.06)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2014.07)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2014.08)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2014.09)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2014.10)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2014.11)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2014.12)

        *IS 2014.03
        *REC(FACTOR = 1)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2014.04)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2014.05)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2014.06)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2014.07)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2014.08)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2014.09)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2014.10)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2014.11)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2014.12)

        *IS 2014.04
        *REC(FACTOR = 1)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2014.05)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2014.06)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2014.07)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2014.08)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2014.09)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2014.10)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2014.11)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2014.12)

        *IS 2014.05
        *REC(FACTOR = 1)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2014.06)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2014.07)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2014.08)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2014.09)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2014.10)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2014.11)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2014.12)

        *IS 2014.06
        *REC(FACTOR = 1)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2014.07)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2014.08)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2014.09)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2014.10)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2014.11)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2014.12)

        *IS 2014.07
        *REC(FACTOR = 1)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2014.08)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2014.09)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2014.10)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2014.11)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2014.12)

        *IS 2014.08
        *REC(FACTOR = 1)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2014.09)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2014.10)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2014.11)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2014.12)

        *IS 2014.09
        *REC(FACTOR = 1)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2014.10)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2014.11)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2014.12)

        *IS 2014.10
        *REC(FACTOR = 1)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2014.11)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2014.12)

        *IS 2014.11
        *REC(FACTOR = 1)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2014.12)

        *IS 2014.12
        *REC(FACTOR = 1)

        *IS 2015.01
        *REC(FACTOR = 1)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2015.02)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2015.03)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2015.04)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2015.05)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2015.06)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2015.07)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2015.08)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2015.09)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2015.10)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2015.11)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2015.12)

        *IS 2015.02
        *REC(FACTOR = 1)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2015.03)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2015.04)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2015.05)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2015.06)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2015.07)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2015.08)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2015.09)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2015.10)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2015.11)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2015.12)

        *IS 2015.03
        *REC(FACTOR = 1)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2015.04)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2015.05)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2015.06)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2015.07)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2015.08)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2015.09)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2015.10)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2015.11)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2015.12)

        *IS 2015.04
        *REC(FACTOR = 1)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2015.05)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2015.06)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2015.07)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2015.08)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2015.09)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2015.10)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2015.11)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2015.12)

        *IS 2015.05
        *REC(FACTOR = 1)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2015.06)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2015.07)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2015.08)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2015.09)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2015.10)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2015.11)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2015.12)

        *IS 2015.06
        *REC(FACTOR = 1)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2015.07)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2015.08)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2015.09)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2015.10)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2015.11)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2015.12)

        *IS 2015.07
        *REC(FACTOR = 1)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2015.08)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2015.09)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2015.10)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2015.11)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2015.12)

        *IS 2015.08
        *REC(FACTOR = 1)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2015.09)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2015.10)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2015.11)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2015.12)

        *IS 2015.09
        *REC(FACTOR = 1)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2015.10)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2015.11)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2015.12)

        *IS 2015.10
        *REC(FACTOR = 1)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2015.11)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2015.12)

        *IS 2015.11
        *REC(FACTOR = 1)
        *REC(FACTOR = 1,TIME = 2015.12)

        *IS 2015.12
        *REC(FACTOR = 1)

    *ENDWHEN
    *IS F99
    *REC(FACTOR = 1)
*ENDWHEN
```

Comment: Is it related to SAP?

Comment: is it really a java code?

Comment: This is not Java. What exactly do you want? Do you want to rewrite this code in Java or something? Or do you need to make a Java program to print the mentioned piece of code?